# C# Forms display ranking list in a messagebox/new form from database/chart

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, datagridview

I made a form that contains a datagridview, button, and a chart. The datagridview shows a **Sales** record of the business. The graph shows the top selling items from the datagridview. It is based from the **quantity** column (number of items sold) of the datagridview. What I want to happen is that when a user clicks the **Generate** button, a messagebox/ new form will appear.
[image]
It will contain a label (**Top 3 Items**) and under that label, there will be a ranking of the best selling items.

[image]

The question is how will I be able to create a ranking list in a messagebox/new form if the data is from a chart/datagridview?

Here's my current code for the form:

```
public partial class CFReport : Form
    {
        public CFReport()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label5.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void CFReport_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'casaFrancaDataSet.Sales' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.salesTableAdapter.Fill(this.casaFrancaDataSet.Sales);

            timer1.Start();
            label5.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
            label6.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Top 3 items:" + Environment.NewLine + "1. " + Environment.NewLine + "2. " + Environment.NewLine + "3. ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have a datatable call Sales.  A messagebox is text and you need to add a CR after each line.  So first you can enumerate through the table : List<int> topThree = Sales.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<int>("Quantity")).OrderbyDescending(x => x).Take(3).ToList();  Then add a return after each line string message = string.Join("\n", topThree);

Answer (score 0):

Try this if I got the question right. You can use LINQ for ordering your chart/datagridview.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WindowsFormsApp9
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Product> products = new List<Product>(); // your chart/datagridview
            products.Add(new Product { Name = "Banana", Price = 1 }); 
            products.Add(new Product { Name = "Orange", Price = 10 }); 
            products.Add(new Product { Name = "Apple", Price = 5 }); // your products
            products = products.OrderByDescending(p => p.Price).ToList(); // ordering products by price
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int i = 1;
            foreach (var product in products)
            {
                sb.Append($"{i}. {product.Name} - {product.Price}\n");
                i++;
            }
            MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
    class Product
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use data binding to separate your data (model) from how the data is displayed (view).

Your DataGridView has a DataSource. Use that to show the data.

```
class DisplayedProduct
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Quantity {get; set;}
    public decimal Price {get; set;}
}
```

Use visual studio designer to create the columns and tell which column should show which property, or do this programmatically.

```
public MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
         this.InitializeComponent();

         this.columnId.DataPropertyName = nameof(DisplayedProdut.Id);
         this.columnName.DataPropertyName = nameof(DislayedProduct.Name);
         ...
    }
```

I'll make a lot of small methods, so they will be easy to understand, easy to reuse, easy to unit test, debug and change:

Fetch the Products:

```
private IEnumerable<DisplayedProduct> FetchProductsToDisplay()
{
    ... // TODO: implement
}
```

Create a property to show the Products and fetch the displayed (and possibly edited) products:

```
private BindingList<DisplayedProduct> DisplayedProducts
{
    get => (BindingList<DisplayedProduct>)this.dataGridView1.DataSource;
    set => this.dataGridView1.DataSource = value;
}
```

And show the products on form loading:

```
private void InitProductDisplay()
{
    this.DisplayedProducts = new BindingList<DisplayedProduct> 
        this.FetchProductsToDisplay.ToList());
}

private void OnFormLoading(object sender, ...)
{
    this.InitProductDisplay();
}
```

This is enough to show the products, and fetch them when needed. All changes made by the operator (add / remove rows, edit cells) are automatically reflected in the binding list.

```
private IEnumerable<DisplayedProduct> GetTopProducts()
{
    return this.DisplayedProduts.OrderByDescending(product => product.Quantity);
}

private string CreateTextTopProducts(int count)
{
    IEnumerable<DisplayedProduct> top3Products = GetTopProducts()
    .Select((product, index) => new
    {
        Index = index + 1,
        // select the properties that you want to show in the messagebox:
        Name = product.Name,
        ...
    })
    .Take(count);

    // use a string builder to efficiently add formatted lines:
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.AppendLine("Top 3 items:");

    foreach (var product in top3Products)
    {
        stringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}. {1}", product.Index, product.Name);
        stringBuilder.AppendLine();
    }
    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Finally the methods to show the top3 products:

```
private void ShowTop3Products()
{
    string displayText = this.CreateTextTop3Products(3);
    MessageBox.Show(this, displayText, ...);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ShowTop3Products();
}
```